# distcp throws java.io.IOException when copying files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, distcp

I'm trying to copy 20TB of HDFS files from one cluster to another, using this single distcp command:

```
hadoop distcp
-Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=16834
-Dmapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=32768
-Dyarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb=32768
-direct -update -delete -m 100
webhdfs://source hdfs://target throws error
```

But it throws the `IOException` below. What does this mean?

> java.io.IOException: DistCp failure: Job job_1711122443047_0032 has failed: Application application_1711122443047_0032 failed2 times due to ApplicationMaster for attempt appattempt_1711122443047_0032_000002 timed out. Failing the application.

Comment: Can you share the complete stacktrace ? The AM can fail for lots of reasons.

Comment: re-running it  doesn't throw error but its very slow even for very small update from snapshot say just 10-20 files update. Any advice to fasten update ?

Comment: You can use multi threaded mapper